# Is there any way to have parallax stretchy header effect on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, parallax

I am working on an iOS application where i need to show parallax stretchy header on UICollectionView while scrolling.

I have implemented the same effect on UITableView in my previous version of app using [this third party class](https://github.com/pyro2927/ParallaxBlur).

Due to some UI requirements, I need to replace UITableView with UICollectionView.
So is there any class equivalent to ParallaxBlur for UICollectionView?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked yourself? What did you find? Have you tried looking at `ParallaxBlur` source code and recode it for `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Thanks @Losiowaty I tried recoding it for UICollectionView, its not working.

Comment: And where did it fail?